# Inherit dynamic object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

I want to create a sub class "sub()" that can inherit either object "A(object)" or object "B(object)".

The following works for this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Class A was inherited"


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Class B was inherited"


class sub(A if inh==A else B):
    def __init__(self,inh):
        if inh==A:
            A.__init__(self)
        else:
            B.__init__(self)
```

However, "inh" is not a defined parameter when I construct my "sub()". I want to be able to construct my "sub()" with an argument "inh" that initialize either "A(object)" or "B(object)".

So that:

```
my_object = sub(inh = A)
```

will give me:

```
Class A was inherited
```

And that:

```
my_object = sub(inh = B)
```

will give me

```
Class B was inherited
```

My problem is, how do I pass "inh" to the constructor "sub()" so it can choose the right object to inherit?

Comment: You cannot. Inheriting is done when creating the type, not when instantiating it. You may create a new class dynamically however.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: I _think_ it should be possible with a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) and [`__new__`](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/new-new-method.html), but I really don't see any scenario where this is the best option.

Comment: Why do you need to inherit? Can you compose instead?

Comment: The reason I want to inherit dynamically is that A(object) and B(object) has the same functions (functions with the same name but returns different results). Instead of doing an "if inh = A:..." for all functions in my super class, I'm simply overwriting what functions my "sub()" calls.

More elegant solutions to this is appreciated.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you are right.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have one class ( could be A). That I use to instantiate different sockets and parse my SCPI instructions to the port. I want to have a debug mode where all the functions inherited from A simply returns a value that emulates my socket instead of actually extablishing connection.

Answer (score 2):

Immortal's solution, while basically right, has a drawback: each call to `Sub()` will yield a new class, so things like `isinstance()` or class identity test will break. A solution to this is to keep a mapping of already created classes:

```
_CLSMAP = {}

def Sub(base, *args, **kw):
    if base not in _CLSMAP:
        class Sub(base):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
                super(sub, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    _CLSMAP[base] = Sub
    return _CLSMAP[base](*args, **kw)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me that what you want is a generator/factory function that will construct and return a class instance as you'd wish.
For that, you can use python's ability to define classes and functions within functions, so that your definition of `class sub` will be done in the scope of the factory function, like this:

```
def Sub(inh=object):
    class sub(inh):
       def __init__(self):
           super(sub, self).__init__()
    return sub()
```

You can now pass the desired subclass to your generator function and get an instantiated instance of the desired type.

Run output:

```
>>> def Sub(inh=object):
...     class sub(inh):
...        def __init__(self):
...            super(sub, self).__init__()
...     return sub()
...
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "Class A was inherited"
...
>>>
>>> class B(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "Class B was inherited"
...
>>>
>>> Sub(A)
Class A was inherited
<__main__.sub object at 0x014E4970>
>>> Sub(B)
Class B was inherited
<__main__.sub object at 0x014E49F0>
>>>
```

is as desired.

Comment: Why `type(inh)` ? If you pass a class as argument, it will the use it's metaclass as base class, which is surely not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Also, this will create a new `sub` class on each invocation, which will screw `isinstance()` tests or identity tests on the class.